# The last vertical border doesn't seem to close my table, what should I do?

Tags: tables

I seem to be having a problem with my table.

[image]

Here's the code I wrote for it, can somebody please tell me how to fix and improve on this?

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.85\textwidth}{|p{0.075\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.075\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
\hline
\centering Motto&&& \\ \hline
\centering Class Number&& \centering Full Name& \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
```

I know I'm a noob at this but I really want to learn.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You used the `tabular*` environment which has a fixed width, In this environment your used columns take up more than the specified width. The right most vertical rule is inserted after your specified width of the used columns but the horizontal lines are only as long as the width specified for the `tabular*` environment. You might be interested in [`tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

Answer (score 1):

My comment into an answer:

The `tabular*` environment takes as its argument a specified width. The horizontal lines are as long as this width. The vertical lines are inserted after the columns, so if the total width of the columns doesn't match the width of the `tabular*` environment, they won't align with the end of the horizontal ones.

An easy solution is to use the `tabularx` package. It provides the `tabularx` environment, which also takes the width it should take as argument, but provides the column specifier `X`, which is like a `p` but taking up the available space. You could change one of your columns to said `X` type:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.85\textwidth}{|p{0.075\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.075\textwidth}|X|}
\hline
\centering Motto&&& \\ \hline
\centering Class Number&& \centering Full Name& \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason why your table is too wide is that you forgot to take the `\tabcolsep`s inserted between the columns into account. Also the vertical rules contribute to the width if the `array` package is loaded (which is a dependency of many table related packages, e.g. of `tabularx`). So to get everything correct with your `tabular*` approach (and a loaded `array.sty`) you'd have to calculate the width of the columns with respect to the `\tabcolsep`s added (two per column if you don't use any `@` notation to change the contents in between columns) -- calculations in the following are done with `\dimexpr`:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.85\linewidth}
  {
    |p{0.075\linewidth}
    |p{0.3\linewidth}
    |p{0.075\linewidth}
    |p{\dimexpr0.85\linewidth-0.075\linewidth-0.3\linewidth-0.075\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
  }
```

Of course you could shorten that to `\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax`. Without a loaded `array.sty` you'd have to leave out the `\arrayrulewidth`:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.85\linewidth}
  {
    |p{0.075\linewidth}
    |p{0.3\linewidth}
    |p{0.075\linewidth}
    |p{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-8\tabcolsep\relax}
  }
```

Those should give the same result as the `tabularx` approach above, but using `tabularx` seems easier...

Comment: @user364155 on this site a thank you is generally expressed with upvotes. Also you should accept the answer which solved your question the best way after waiting a reasonable amount of time for other/better answers.

Comment: I upvoted, but since I am relatively new and my reputation is below 15, it says that the upvotes do not change the display. But thanks all the same.

Comment: @user364155 Oh, I forgot about that... If you stay here you'll eventually earn enough reputation to vote :)